# Dozer mapping ArrayList contained in object

Tags: java, arraylist, dozer

I have an object A that contain an arrayList and I want to map it to an object B with the same structure of A.
After the mapping the arrayList of object B is null.
I tried this mapping.

```
<mapping type="bi-directional">
    <class-a>it.firstpackage.A</class-a>
    <class-b>it.secondpackage.B</class-b>
    <field copy-by-reference="true">
        <a>collection</a>
        <b>collection</b>
        <a-hint>it.firstpackage.ListA</a-hint>
        <b-hint>it.secondpackage.ListB</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Can you tell me where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map collection by reference what tells dozer not to map subelements but copy the value as it is.
But this way it cannot copy the property since they are of different types. 
Try removing copy-by-reference and add mapping between lista and listb if needed.

Comment: If you intend in this manner:
<mapping type="bi-directional">
    <class-a>it.firstpackage.A</class-a>
    <class-b>it.secondpackage.B</class-b>
</mapping>

<mapping type="bi-directional">
    <class-a>it.firstpackage.ListA</class-a>
    <class-b>it.secondpackage.ListB</class-b>
</mapping>  
I get the same problem: null in List

Comment: I dont know how lista and listb are structured but i think you may need to map the internal representation on lista and listb using field elements.

Comment: Supposing that fields "collection" contained in A and B are two lists containing objects of type Object (List<Object>), can you show me a practical sample of how you would map objects A and B? Thanks

Comment: <mapping>
  <class-a>package.POBLACIONESA</class-a>
  <class-b>package.POBLACIONESB</class-b>
  <field relationship-type="cumulative">
   <a>POBLACIONS</a>
   <b is-accessible="false">POBLACIONS</b>
   
  </field>
 </mapping>

Comment: do they lists it.firstpackage.A.collection and it.firstpackage.B.collection  store the same type of Object ?